# Find a substring location in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

In PL/SQL we have instr predefined function, which returns the nth position of a substring in a column from a starting position. Does a similar function exist in Pig?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INDEXOF`.

```
A = LOAD 'file' using PigStorage() as (a:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE INDEXOF(a,'search character',0);
```